# Using ajax and $.each repeating output

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I need your help here. Every single time I am trying to display a content it displayed a few times (usually 4) but should be shown just ones. I don't know what is the problem with my code. Which is below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://' + subParam + '.domain.name/' + akey + '/get_article',
    async: false,
    callback: 'callback',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data, status) {
        if (data !== undefined && data.post !== undefined) {
            if (data !== undefined && data.post.author.description > 0) {
                if (data.post.thumbnail_images.large.url !== undefined) {
                    $.each(data.post.thumbnail_images, function (i2, type) {
                        $('#news').append('<div id="nimg" style="background-image: url(' + data.post.thumbnail_images.large.url + ')"></div><a href="author.html?type=authors&id=' + data.post.author.description + '"><div id="circletag" style="background-image: url(' + data.post.author.nickname + ')"></div></a><div id="newstext"><div id="newstitle">' + data.post.title + '</div><div>' + data.post.content + '</div><div><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'' + data.post.custom_fields.syndication_permalink + '#comments\', \'_system\', \'location=yes\');" id="verstovcomments"></a></div></div>');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#news').append('<div id="nimg" style="background-image: url(' + defaultNews + ')"></div><a href="author.html?type=authors&id=' + data.post.author.description + '"><div id="circletag" style="background-image: url(' + data.post.author.nickname + ')"></div></a><div id="newstext"><div id="newstitle">' + data.post.title + '</div><div>' + data.post.content + '</div><div><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'' + data.post.custom_fields.syndication_permalink + '#comments\', \'_system\', \'location=yes\');" id="verstovcomments"></a></div></div>');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

....

And my json response looks like:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "post": {
        "id": 3211,
        "title": "title",
        "content": "content"
        "thumbnail": "/uploads\/2013\/09\/matkapital-150x150.jpg",
        "thumbnail_size": "thumbnail",
        "thumbnail_images": {
           "full": {
                "url": "/uploads\/2013\/09\/matkapital.jpg",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 427
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "/uploads\/2013\/09\/matkapital-150x150.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "/uploads\/2013\/09\/matkapital-250x166.jpg",
                "width": 250,
                "height": 166
            },
            "large": {
                "url": "/uploads\/2013\/09\/matkapital-640x426.jpg",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 426
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it because I am using `$.each` or there is the other issue?

Comment: After the content field in you JSON a comma is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just changed thumbnail_images to custom_fields in $.each(data.post.thumbnail_images, function (i2, type) and it stopped multiply results.

```
 $.ajax({
url: 'https://' + subParam + '.domain.name/' + akey + '/get_article',
async: false,
callback: 'callback',
crossDomain: true,
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function (data, status) {
    if (data !== undefined && data.post !== undefined) {
        if (data !== undefined && data.post.author.description > 0) {
            if (data.post.thumbnail_images.large.url !== undefined) {
                $.each(data.post.custom_fields, function (i2, type) {
                    $('#news').append('<div id="nimg" style="background-image: url(' + data.post.thumbnail_images.large.url + ')"></div><a href="author.html?type=authors&id=' + data.post.author.description + '"><div id="circletag" style="background-image: url(' + data.post.author.nickname + ')"></div></a><div id="newstext"><div id="newstitle">' + data.post.title + '</div><div>' + data.post.content + '</div><div><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'' + data.post.custom_fields.syndication_permalink + '#comments\', \'_system\', \'location=yes\');" id="verstovcomments"></a></div></div>');
                });
            } else {
                $('#news').append('<div id="nimg" style="background-image: url(' + defaultNews + ')"></div><a href="author.html?type=authors&id=' + data.post.author.description + '"><div id="circletag" style="background-image: url(' + data.post.author.nickname + ')"></div></a><div id="newstext"><div id="newstitle">' + data.post.title + '</div><div>' + data.post.content + '</div><div><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'' + data.post.custom_fields.syndication_permalink + '#comments\', \'_system\', \'location=yes\');" id="verstovcomments"></a></div></div>');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there is no `author` property in the json, so the conditon `if (data !== undefined && data.post.author.description > 0) {` will throw an error saying `data.post.author` is undefined.

So change the condition `if (data !== undefined && data.post.author.description > 0) {` to `if (data.post.author && data.post.author.description) {` and try

In this case your data will not display anything because there is no author data in the given json

Comment: if we will exclude that line can be the probem within:    $.each(data.post.thumbnail_images, function(i2, type) {

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look into a JS templating engine like doT.js.

Then you can easily create a clean markup structure and just dump your json data to the templating engine... the whole iteration and output is done by itself and your JS code is free of these barely unreadable markup concatenations.

here would be a little example:

```
// normally you would have the templace in
// a <script type="text/dotjs-or-so"> block and load it with jquery.

var jsonData = {"array":["banana","apple","orange"]};
var tplstring = 
'{{~it.array :value:index}}'
    +'<div>{{=value}}!</div>'
+'{{~}}';
var tpl = doT.template(tplString);
// render it somewhere
$('#someThing').html(
   tpl(jsonData)
);
```

See http://olado.github.io/doT/